# sticky issue - frame within frame

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

in this example why the text does not stick to the left...

I also tried to pack them in a different way but without success...

some help please?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.geometry("400x200")


frame0 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(window)
frame01 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(frame0)
frame02 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(frame0)


frame0.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame01.grid(row=1, column=0)
frame02.grid(row=2, column=0)


btn1 = tkinter.ttk.Button(frame01, text="btn1")
btn2= tkinter.ttk.Button(frame01, text="btn2")

btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn2.grid(row=0, column=1)

label = tkinter.ttk.Label(frame02, text="text")

label.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

oh ..I should stick it from the frame lol...

```
frame02.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26619961)

Comment: Why you think it's not a complete answer ?